# Using struct with Perl XS

Tags: c, perl, xs

I am new to Perl XS and I am trying to convert a C function to Perl subroutine.

I have the following C function

```
void parse(struct parser *result, const char *string, size_t len);
```

where the `parse` function accepts a pointer to `struct parser`, a string and the length of the string. `struct parser` is defined something like this:

```
struct parser {
    char *data;
    long  a;
    long  b;
    long  c;
};
```

The function stores its results in the `result` argument.

I want to convert this function to Perl XS. What I am doing is something like this:

```
struct parser *result
parse_xs (string)
    const char* string
PREINIT:
    long len = strlen(string);
CODE:
    struct parser par;
    parse(&par,s,len);
    RETVAL = par;
OUTPUT:
    RETVAL
```

How can I change the above code to run `parse_xs` in Perl code like this

```
my $result = parse_xs();

print $result->data; # will print the data field from the struct.
```

where `$result` is the result of the `parse` C function.

Comment: You'll need to create an XS func. What's `data`'s type?

Comment: its char * i added the struct fields to the questions to make it more clear.

Comment: You may be interested in [Inline::Struct](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Inline-Struct/Struct.pod). Even if you don't want to use Inline in your code (because the entire premise of Inline is pretty crazy), it might be useful in development - you can probably intercept the XS code that it generates and use that as a crib sheet.

Answer (score 6):

First, you have to choose a name for your result class. I'll simply use `ParseResult` from now on.

You'll also need a [`typemap`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxstypemap.html) file. To map C structs to Perl classes, use the built-in `T_PTROBJ`:

```c
TYPEMAP
ParseResult     T_PTROBJ
```

Then add a typedef and the `ParseResult` package to your XS code:

```
typedef struct parser *ParseResult;

MODULE = YourModule  PACKAGE = ParseResult
```

Make sure that the typedef comes before all `MODULE` sections. Now you can add the XSUB for the `parse_xs` function (you should probably just name it `parse`):

```c
ParseResult
parse_xs(string)
    SV *string
PREINIT:
    const char *c_string;
    STRLEN len;
CODE:
    Newx(RETVAL, 1, struct parser);
    c_string = SvPV(string, len);
    parse(RETVAL, c_string, len);
OUTPUT:
    RETVAL
```

Note that I allocate memory for the result struct using Perl's [`Newx`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html#Memory-Allocation) function. Returning a pointer to a struct on the stack cannot work. I also added some minor optimizations like passing the string as `SV` and getting the content and length using [`SvPV`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html#Working-with-SVs).

In order to free the allocated memory, you have to implement a destructor (named `DESTROY` in Perl):

```c
void
DESTROY(result)
    ParseResult result
CODE:
    /* Possibly free data in result here. */
    Safefree(result);
```

Your result struct probably points to other allocated memory. Make sure to free this memory before calling `Safefree`.

Then you can write accessors like this:

```c
const char *
data(result)
    ParseResult result
CODE:
    RETVAL = result->data;
OUTPUT:
    RETVAL
```

Now you have to write a Perl module for your class. Add a file named `ParseResult.pm` with the following contents:

```perl
package ParseResult;
use strict;
use warnings;

use XSLoader;

our $VERSION = '0.01';
XSLoader::load('ParseResult', $VERSION);

1;
```

Your new XS-based class can then be used like this:

```perl
use ParseResult;

my $result = ParseResult::parse_xs('input');
print $result->data, "\n";
```

Note that I use a fully-qualified name for `parse_xs`. If you want to call it without the class name, you have to export it from `ParseResult.pm`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use C struct as Perl Object.
See the following page(This page is Japanese, but you may understand source code).

http://d.hatena.ne.jp/perlcodesample/20140807/1407291461

```
// creat struct as pointer
Point* point = (Point*)malloc(sizeof(Point));
point->x = x;
point->y = y;


// Convert pointer to size_t
size_t point_iv = PTR2IV(point);

// Convert size_t to SV*
SV* point_sv = sv_2mortal(newSViv(point_iv));

// Create reference to SV*
SV* point_svrv = sv_2mortal(newRV_inc(point_sv));

// Create Object
SV* point_obj = sv_bless(point_svrv, gv_stashpv(class_name, 1));
```